# Excel: How to prevent users from accessing Design Mode

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook that is fully automated, with formulas, links, Macros, password-protection, etc. It is a template file that's password locked and empty spaces for users to fill up. To make it as secure as possible, both the worksheet itself and the VBA code are protected.

The problem right now is that being relatively Macro-heavy, a user enabling Design Mode will render the worksheet both unprotected (to a certain degree) and crippled in its functions. Therefore, a tech-saavy person (I mean, I'm not that good and even I can break my own code. lol) by accessing Design Mode could potentially wreck havoc on the file. While the file does not exactly contain sensitive information, it contains very important documentation the shouldn't be tampered with.

I'm not expected the average Joe to break the file (since most people here don't even know Developer exists). However, being important files, I want to foolproof it as much as I possibly can. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I am guessing you know that almost anyone can unlock protected book/sheet/project in few minutes with a quick internet search if they really want to. Maybe handling the `CommandBars.FindControl(ID:=1605).OnAction = "subName"` event to detect the change https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.excel.programming/XN27a-Gxz6g

Comment: @Slai This even with a password protection? (Both the worksheet and the VBA) It also should have admin control on the file itself to be read only (they need to save as). They furthermore can't download anything from the internet into the computer in question since it's a controlled atmosphere.
They want it in an Excel File, so I don't have much choice. I just had to do it to be as secure as I can. Considering I don't expect them to know developer even exists, I doubt it'll be that quick to crack, maybe? But better safe the sorry.

Comment: In Excel 2007 there was no way to modify the Ribbon from within Excel so we used RibbonX modifications.  This enabled, among other things, disabling certain Ribbon commands and or groups for a given workbook so that they couldn't be used at all - even from VBA.  RibbonX can still be used in later versions of Excel.  See [Ron de Bruin's Excel Automation site](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win001.htm) for details.